# Code blocks: remove leading spaces

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Often I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6175770/edit/95363a84-8dc9-4c7a-8ec6-332d9fa94e29).

```
          foreach ($langs as $lang => $val){
            if ($val === '') $langs[$lang] = 1;
          }
```

This annoys me and often creates unnecessary horizontal scrolling, so I tend to fix it by removing the leading spaces. Resulting in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6175770/edit/613e24bf-4dc2-46a1-b6cc-0a32d0bf7fd6).

```
foreach ($langs as $lang => $val){
  if ($val === '') $langs[$lang] = 1;
}
```

After doing it a lot, I got bored, as the only way is deleting the spaces manually, separately on each line.
I did check out [this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34588/4-spaces-for-code-tags-is-annoying) and gave [this tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34588/4-spaces-for-code-tags-is-annoying/34768#34768) a shot, but it won't remove the annoying spaces.

May I therefore make a proposal:
**When <s>Ctrl+K</s> Ctrl+Shift+K is pressed, check if certain number of spaces can be safely removed from the beginning of each line.** If so, remove that (same) number of spaces from each line, resulting in the least-indented lines being exactly 4 spaces to the right.

Relative indentation is obviously not affected, so the code remains formatted as the author wanted it, but shifted to the left as a whole.

And may **Ctrl+K** retain its default behaviour, because there's Fortran 77 as **dmckee** [noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93219/code-blocks-remove-leading-spaces/93223#93223).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic code reindent button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82671/automatic-code-reindent-button)

Comment: ctrl+shift+K??? I've always put the spaces there manually. I feel so stupid.

Comment: @Tim Just Ctrl+K. I'm trying to suggest Ctrl+Shift+K as the "also remove leading spaces" mode.

Answer (score 3):

Column formatted Fortran. 'nuff said.

Comment: Riiight... Didn't know that. See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the code block, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. Each time you press it, one level of indentation is removed from the entire block. This is a very quick and easy way to remove superfluous indentation.

Problem solved. No need for a new feature.

Comment: Well, yes, that sort of helps, but it removes spaces 4 at a time, so it can still leave 1-3 unwanted spaces.

Comment: @GSerg: I try not to let 1 or 2 spaces ruin my day. Having the code indented by less than 4 spaces isn't really a problem. Some people even do it intentionally to set it off from the body text even more.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with tabs?